# displaying single value from a different dataframe in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I'm trying to display a single value in my ggplot, but from a different data frame than the rest of the plot data. Basically, I just want to insert "d = [value from second dataframe]" in a corner of the graph. All of the advice points to using geom_text(), but I can't seem to get the syntax right. Here's the data reprex.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(junior = c(4,3,2,2,4,3,2), 
                 senior = c(2,6,3,5,2,6,3))
longdf <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = 'class', values_to = 'rating')

df2 <- data.frame(p = .002, d = 0.64)
```

... and here is the plot code. I'm not sure what exactly would go in geom_text(), or if it's even possible to import a single data point from another dataframe. I also need to reference the data point vs. just pasting in the text "d = 0.64".

```
ggplot(data = longdf, aes(x = class, y = rating)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(data = df2, label = d)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `label = d` in `aes()`, and specify `x` and `y` positions:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = longdf, aes(x = class, y = rating)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_text(data = df2, aes(x = 2.4, y = 2, label = paste("d =", d)))
```

Note that you don’t *have* to put the label values in a dataframe. You can also use `annotate()`:

```r
ggplot(data = longdf, aes(x = class, y = rating)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 2.4, y = 2, label = "d = 0.64")
```

[image]